# fast way to compare time objects in R

Tags: r, posixct

let's assume the following `data.frame`

```
set.seed(20221117)
df <- data.frame(x = as.POSIXct(sample(2e9, 1e5), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC"),
                 y = as.POSIXct(sample(2e9, 1e5), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC"))
```

What would be a reasonably fast way to select the maximum for each row (ideally without having to explicitely convert into `double`)?

Comment: `library(microbenchmark); microbenchmark({df$later <- ifelse(df$x < df$y, df$y, df$x)}, times=100)` gives an average run time of just over 11 milliseconds on my machine.  And `microbenchmark({df$later <- max(df$y, df$x)}, times=100)` just over 2 milliseconds.  How fast do you want?

Comment: @Limey ifelse converts it back to atomic double vector.

Comment: @sindri_baldur  And my failure to notice the "rowwise" element of OP's question makes my code incorrect anyway!  But the point about benchmarking/speed remains relevant.

Comment: @Limey how does the "rowwise" element make your approach incorrect (other than the atomic double part)?

Comment: Could use dplyr::if_else()  or data.table::fifelse().

Comment: @Tom: because `df$later <- max(df$y, df$x)` (and my other suggestion) calculates the maximum value in any row of either of `df$x` and `df$y` and populates every entry in `df$later` with that value.  Try it and see.

Comment: @Limey: I did and using `as.POSIXct(..., origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC")` the `ifelse`- suggestion agrees with the result obtained from the `pmax` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do.call(pmax, df)

[1] "2020-11-30 22:09:29 GMT" "2026-06-14 20:00:05 GMT"
[3] "2008-02-08 01:32:23 GMT" "2021-06-17 10:44:05 GMT"
[5] "2025-02-18 23:20:28 GMT" "1997-03-27 18:10:44 GMT"
...
```

Benchmarking

```
bench::mark(
  Sindr = do.call(pmax, df),
  Tom   = df %>%  
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(max = max(c(x, y))) %>%
    pull(max)
)

  expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 Sindr        2.29ms  4.14ms   176.       6.49MB    49.9     88    25
2 Tom           6.59s   6.59s     0.152   24.09MB     7.28     1    48
```

Comment: I believe speed was the focus of OP's question, not "how".

Answer (score 0):

In `data.frame` format you can:

```
df %>%  
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(c(x, y)))

# A tibble: 100,000 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   x                   y                   max                
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2032-12-21 10:50:13 1994-12-09 15:36:53 2032-12-21 10:50:13
 2 1988-03-11 14:43:53 1982-05-23 23:39:28 1988-03-11 14:43:53
 3 2004-10-17 08:34:41 1986-06-02 03:05:07 2004-10-17 08:34:41
 4 2028-03-02 09:27:44 1986-09-11 02:46:20 2028-03-02 09:27:44
 5 1985-02-17 09:39:02 2002-08-13 05:42:29 2002-08-13 05:42:29
 6 1977-08-04 13:26:26 2021-05-22 14:48:48 2021-05-22 14:48:48
 7 1995-05-21 01:13:46 2004-07-19 05:13:18 2004-07-19 05:13:18
 8 1988-03-26 21:59:08 1999-06-13 08:34:06 1999-06-13 08:34:06
 9 1977-11-15 23:54:57 2026-07-15 12:59:39 2026-07-15 12:59:39
10 2031-07-26 16:51:17 2017-01-12 15:23:15 2031-07-26 16:51:17
# … with 99,990 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I believe speed was the focus of OP's question, not "how".